# What can be the maximum size of iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimage, compression

I have some 1.5 GBs of images and videos in my app bundle. Will apple allow such a huge size app?

Can we optimize the app to bring the size down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apple will allow apps of any size on the App Store. As a point of reference, the game Infinity Blade III is 1.92GB.

But keep in mind that apps (or their updates) over 100MB cannot be downloaded over cellular, so if it's possible to structure the app in such a way to accommodate that (i.e., download the videos and images separately etc), then that will definitely help.

Comment: Ah. I stand corrected. There is an upper limit, and it was recently updated. As of February 12, 2015, app binaries can be up to 4GB in size.